# Missing photos on my iPhone

Tags: icloud, photos.app

I have a Macbook Pro and an iPhone that share the same iCloud account. On my Macbook's Photos I have a smart album that contains 52 photos. On the iPhone the album contains 40, with 12 photos are missing.

How can I resync the missing 12 photos with the iPhone?

Comment: Is this using the Photos app or iPhoto on your Macbook?

Comment: Using Photos, and I imported the library from iPhoto to Photos.

Comment: Are you using iCloud Photo Library, or syncing photos through iTunes?

Comment: Yes I'm using the iCloud photo library.

Answer (score -1):

Smart Albums are not fully supported yet. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204478

I would suggest trying to create a new smart album, perhaps with slightly different parameters, and see if you can work around the bug. Or, worst case, you could create a regular album.

Comment: It's unclear how you get either of your conclusions (that Smart Albums are "not fully supported yet", and that this is a "bug") from the document you linked. It states that criterion that were supported in iPhoto or Aperture, but are not supported in Photos, are removed from the converted Smart Album. I read this as saying that certain criterion were available in iPhoto or Aperture but are no longer available. For example, iPhoto had Events, which are not in Photos. Therefore a Smart Album using a criterion regarding an Event's name would not be possible, but that is no way a bug.

Comment: I saw this bug myself where Smart Albums that have been imported from iPhoto to Photos.app are not fully intact. Using a non-smart Album as I suggested would be a test whether this is the problem.